# Count grouping by specific date intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count the amount of "services" a customer have in 30 days period groups, since the contract start day. So I have to count the services in a monthly based period since his start date. Simplifying the table is something like this:

```
services  
------------------
id serial   
id_customer bigint  
service_date date
```

Lets imaging there is only one type of service. I solve it like this:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_PART('year',service_date)||'-'|| CASE WHEN DATE_PART('day',service_date) >= 15 THEN 
    DATE_PART('month',service_date)
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN DATE_PART('month',service_date) = 1 THEN 
        12 
    ELSE 
        DATE_PART('month',service_date)-1 
    END
  END bill, count(id) 
FROM services
WHERE id_customer = 1
GROUP BY bill
```

results would be

```
bill    | count
-------------------
2019-02 | 2455333
```

In the example the start date for id_customer 1 is 2019-02-15 but for 2019-02 period I will be counting the services until 2019-03-14.

What I want to know is, there is a better/more efficient solution?

I saw the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438280/count-with-date-intervals) but implies an INNER JOIN with a GROUP BY with the same table which I think it would be slower, because my table has a lot of records.

Comment: I just realize that the special case for month 1 affects the year too, so the CASE WHEN structure has to change, but that doesn't affect the nature of my question

Comment: Where/how do you store the start date for a customer or is that the same across all customers? And the name of the period always relates to the month where the period started?

Comment: The start date is different for each customer, is stored in other table. In the example is the literal 15 in the query, at the end I could meka a function with the start day as a parameter. And yes the name of the period will be related to the month when the period start

Comment: The problem of a start day 29,30 or 31 could be overlook

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about the actual number of days in a month nor the month, year or day-of-month.

Just use the start date for a customer and let PostgreSQL generate the correct billing cycle periods for you.

To run a single query over all customers, I have used a separate table with the customer `id` as well as a `billing_start` date configured, for which we can then run a query such as the following:

```sql
WITH
    periods (id, period_start, period_end) AS (
        SELECT
            id,
            generate_series(billing_start, current_date, '1 month'::interval)::date,
            (generate_series(billing_start, current_date, '1 month'::interval) + '1 month'::interval)::date
        FROM test_customers
    ),
    data AS (
        SELECT
            periods.id AS customer,
            period_start,
            count(test_services.*) AS service_calls
        FROM periods INNER JOIN test_services ON (test_services.id_customer = periods.id)
        WHERE test_services.service_date >= periods.period_start AND test_services.service_date < periods.period_end
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    )
SELECT customer, to_char(period_start, 'YYYY-MM') AS bill, service_calls
FROM data
ORDER BY 1, 2
;
```

...resulting in an output such as the following:

```
 customer |  bill   | service_calls 
----------+---------+---------------
        1 | 2018-12 |        382736
        1 | 2019-01 |        382735
        1 | 2019-02 |        345696
        2 | 2018-12 |        382736
        2 | 2019-01 |        382734
        2 | 2019-02 |        234580
        3 | 2018-12 |        382734
        3 | 2019-01 |        382736
        3 | 2019-02 |        123463
        4 | 2018-12 |        382734
        4 | 2019-01 |        382736
        4 | 2019-02 |         12346
        5 | 2019-01 |        382735
        5 | 2019-02 |        283965
        6 | 2019-01 |        382735
        6 | 2019-02 |        172848
        7 | 2019-01 |        382734
        7 | 2019-02 |         61732
        8 | 2019-02 |        333351
        9 | 2019-02 |        222234
       10 | 2019-02 |        111117
(21 rows)
```

Complete online example: https://rextester.com/IHLJ95398

An important thing to note for this to be fast is a multi-column index on `id_customer` and `service_date` because that's where the counting takes place, which then can be done without sorting:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx_svc_customer_date ON test_services (id_customer, service_date);
```

*(otherwise, the sorting will most likely be done on disk, rather than in memory for large data sets)*

If you just want the cycles for a single customer, use it like this:

```sql
WITH
    periods (id, period_start, period_end) AS (
        SELECT
            id,
            generate_series(billing_start, current_date, '1 month'::interval)::date,
            (generate_series(billing_start, current_date, '1 month'::interval) + '1 month'::interval)::date
        FROM test_customers WHERE id = 4
    ),
    data AS (
        SELECT
            periods.id AS customer,
            period_start,
            count(test_services.*) AS service_calls
        FROM periods INNER JOIN test_services ON (test_services.id_customer = periods.id)
        WHERE test_services.service_date >= periods.period_start AND test_services.service_date < periods.period_end
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    )
SELECT customer, to_char(period_start, 'YYYY-MM') AS bill, service_calls
FROM data
ORDER BY 1, 2
;
```

...giving:

```
  bill   | service_calls 
---------+---------------
 2018-12 |        382734
 2019-01 |        382736
 2019-02 |         12346
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the generate_series function. Your solution seems to be the correct way to do it, but in my tests, my implementation runs a couple of seconds faster

Comment: Yes, you don't join them with the actual customer (for the billing start date) which is always more efficient (less temporary data to keep). I've played around a bit and found that my query is a bit sub-optimal for the larger data sets and improved it from [~17 seconds](https://explain.depesz.com/s/mlP2) to [~3 seconds](https://explain.depesz.com/s/TTFT). I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Updated for two optimizations: add the multi-column index and defer the `to_char` to the final output **after** grouping (because `to_char` really gets costly on CPU)